# PHP проверка на число

Tags: php

Как в php проверить является ли переменная целым положительным число. Именно целым (дробное не допускается), т.е. функция is_numeric не подходит. ( is_int тоже не подходит  )

Comment: а разве int это не целое число? и проверка int > 0

Comment: Внизу столько гк настрочили .

Comment: @Error, здесь принято вместо понтов кидаться ответами ;)

Comment: Уточните, как по-вашему должны пройти проверку следующие примеры:
5, '5', 007, -007, 0x007, array(5)

Answer (score 3):

```
if (($val = intval($val)) && ($val > 0))
  ...
```

Comment: полный бред, даже не говоря о том, что вы имели ввиду == вместо =.

Сами подумаути пусть $val='5g';

if ('5g'==intval('5g')) && ('5g'>0)

Что имеем 

if (5==5) && (5>0) вернёт true. Вот так.

Comment: Обоснуйте?

Comment: если бы вы написали идеентично ===, что гда бы работало.

Что тут обосновывать, почитайте по преобразование типов. (в часности когда идёт сравнение string и integer)/

Comment: Вообще я рассчитывал, что вам с переменной этой работать. Если нужна просто проверка, то ответ @ling вам в помощь, и то '5' !== 5. "Почитайте", лол. Я не имел в виду, что там ==, и `'5g'!=intval('5g')`. Мой пример просто из любой переменной делает int и если он положительный - выполняет код. При "5g" рабочее $val будет 5, при отрицательных и 0 - не выполнится, при положительных - выполнится. 

Если вам надо что-то другое - формулируйте вопрос конкретнее. Таких проверок - десятки.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (preg_match('/^\+?\d+$/', $value)) {
    echo "Целое положительное число :-)";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
if ($value && ctype_digit((string)$value)) {
    echo "$value is positive integer\n";
}
```

Или так:

```
$value = filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array("options" => array("min_range" => 1)));
if ($value !== faslse) {
    echo "$value is positive integer\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( ( is_int( $a ) || ctype_digit( $a ) ) && $a > 0 )

if ( ( is_int( $a ) || (string) intval( $a ) === $a ) && $a > 0 )

if ( ( preg_match( '/^[1-9]\d*$/', $a ) ) || ( is_int( $a ) && $a > 0 ) )
```

P.S: Существует бесконечное кол-во способов решения вашего туманно сформулированного вопроса

Comment: может и существует множество способов, но точно не ваш. 
$a='5'; is_int($a) - string

Comment: Теперь то что вы хотели...

Answer (score 1):

```
if(intval($a) === $a && $a > 0){...}
```

Comment: только щас понял. и это не работает. если 5 будет интегер

Comment: вот только не рабочий ( м.б не на всех php )... 

    if ( '5' === intval('5') ) echo 'ok';

Comment: С '5' не работает - это не число, а строка. Если вам не нужно соответствие типов, пишите через ==.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(is_integer($int) && $int > 0){
   echo 'Это число. И оно больше нуля';
}
else{
   echo 'Не, не катит';
}
```

Comment: `is_integer('5') => false`

Comment: Всё правильно , это строка

Comment: Так можно было каменты прочитать, автор там отписался, что `is_int()` не катит как раз по этой причине. В тексте вопроса, кстати, тоже это есть.

Comment: Цитирую топик "Как в php проверить является ли переменная целым положительным число" . Автор сам не знает чего хочет

Comment: @Error, жаль только автор никак этого не понимает...

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = 100;
//$a = '1a';
//$a = 0;
//$a = '1,1';
//$a = 1.1;
//$a  = 'a';

if(!intval($a) or $a < 1 or !preg_match('/^\+?\d+$/', $a))
{
    echo 'BaD';
}
else
{
    echo 'GooD';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($val *= 1 && $val > 0) {
    echo 'ok';
}
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

a gettype() ?

Answer (score 0):

```
function is_whole_int($val) {
    return is_numeric($val) && floor($val) == $val && $val > 0;
}

var_dump(is_whole_int(5.8)); // false
var_dump(is_whole_int(0)); // false
var_dump(is_whole_int(-1)); // false
var_dump(is_whole_int(5)); // true
```

Переделано отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772603/check-if-number-is-decimal
Вполне логично округлить до целого и сравнить значение. Если нужно число, включая 0, то
`return is_numeric( $val ) && floor( $val ) == $val && $val >= 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Уже предложена куча вариантов, но я бы наверное сделал так

```
if (((int) $val === intval($val)) && intval($val) > 0 && 
preg_match('/^\d+$/', $val))
{
    echo 'is int';
}
else
{
    echo 'not int or < 0';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if(is_numeric($val) && intval($val)>0 && intval($val) == ceil(intval($val))) {

}
```

Answer (score -2):

как вариант проверь сначала is_numeric, а потом проверь что в строке отсутствуют знаки '+' и '.' и ','

Comment: да я уже думал так, но нету ли более простого способа?

Answer (score -3):

Мне нравится такое решение, всегда использую:

```
$v = "dfgf";
if ((int)$v) > 0) {
  echo "Целое положительное";
}
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?